# Connecting via Java from Ubuntu Subsystem or a Linux docker container to SQL Server which is installed on Windows

Tags: java, sql-server, linux, docker, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a `sql` server database which is installed on windows out of a Linux docker container or from an `ubuntu` subsystem with java code and it is not working.
I need a real hardcore expert on this field. I know there are many solutions out there to this problem and I tried many of them, but nothing worked. The special case is that the SQL Server is installed on Windows and I have a linux docker container, so the connection has to be between os. I have tried jtds and jdbc.
Here is the code which works when is executed on windows but not on linux subsystem or docker.
I also tried "useNTLMv2=true" in the connectionstring:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.*;
import net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver;
public class helloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws  ClassNotFoundException {
//String connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<db_ip>:1433;databaseName=someDB;useNTLMv2=true;";
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server_ip>:1433;databaseName=someDB;username=xyz;password=123";
       Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
            String SQL = "SELECT [PLZ] FROM [City]";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

            // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("PLZ"));
            }
        }
        // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

And here ist the exception I am getting from the docker container using jtds:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
            at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:436)
            at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
            at de.arz.pharmafakt.datadelivery.Main.main(Main.java:93)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
            at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.createSocketForJDBC3(SharedSocket.java:288)
            at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.<init>(SharedSocket.java:251)
            at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:331)
```

An ohter exception with the same code I get from ubuntu subsystem:

```
java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: GSS Failed: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:654)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:371)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
        at helloWorld.main(helloWorld.java:16)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: GSS Failed: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.sendMSLoginPkt(TdsCore.java:1976)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:617)
```

Here is my code jdbc:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class helloWorld {
            public static void main(String[] args) {

        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://<server_ip>:1433;databaseName=someDB;user=xyz;password=123;Encrypt=false";

        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); Statement stmt = con.createStatement();) {
                                 String SQL = "SELECT PLZ FROM city";

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

            // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("PLZ") );
            }
        }
        // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

                        }
        }
```

And here is the exception I am getting with ubuntu:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 
'xyz'. ClientConnectionId:21e99cbc-bd73-40a0-8101-542ddffb3a0b
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:265)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:305)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:138)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:42)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:6490)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:5068)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:5002)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7685)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:4048)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3487)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:3077)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2919)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1787)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1229)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
        at helloWorld.main(helloWorld.java:16)
```

I tried almost all solution which are published on the internet to this problem.
I am expecting to see how I could connect to sql server which is installed on windows from linux.

Comment: The different error messages are due to very different reasons. If you get that a connection failed the server port can't be reached. Probably not very unexpected with the setup you are mentioning for a docker container as the docker container is not running directly in the Windows system, but in some kind of Linux subsystem and then there must be some kind of port forward in place in the Linux subsystem to be able to reach the Windows system.

Comment: If you connect from a program running in the Linux subsystem instead, there should be no reason why you wouldn't be able to connect as long as the SQL-server is responding to calls made on a network between the two. If you get the error `Login failed for user` that implies that you have indeed been able to connect to the SQL server but are failing on login. In that case you should check login credentials.

Comment: jTDS hasn't been updated in very nearly ten years. Is there a particular reason you're trying to use it?

Comment: Since your JDBC connection seems to be connecting, just not authenticating, are you able to connect to the target server with SSMS? Have a look in the SQL Server Logs node for 18456 Login failure messages, take note of their `State` numbers, and compare them against those listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to see why the login attempts are failing.

Comment: Sorry but the question was not well formulated there are some missunderstanding. The docker container is not running on a subsystem but I tried two different approches to connect to sql server the first one was through the ubuntu subsystem the second through a linux docker container.

Comment: Docker containers are essentially Linux VMs that run inside WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). They cannot use Active Directory/Windows credentials because they aren't domain joined, you need to install and configure Kerberos modules and setup `kinit`, etc., if you want to go that route. With Ubuntu and/or Docker it's usually much easier to use username+password based SQL Logon credentials unless you have a business reason to do otherwise. That implies that your SQL Server instance must be configured to accept SQL Logon credentials and that you've also created the necessary SQL Logon accounts.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Trying jtds was just pure desperation

Comment: Yeah, forget about AD, it's hard enough to get working between two windows machines. The last version looks more promising, make sure you actually send correct password though

Comment: Did you ever get around to checking the Error 18456 events in the SQL Server Logs as previously suggested?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: I check the Logs here is it:  
Login failed for user 'xyz'. Reason: Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server Authentication

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I also found this in the Logs: 
Cause: No login could be found that matches the specified name.

Comment: Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by my database administrator, he created a login user who is capable of sql authentication. But first I had to check the SQL Server Logs to see what the problem was in detail, like in the comments suggested.